# While loops list index out of range error. Strip off strings with double slases

Tags: python

I was wondering if could help me debug this code. I'm curious as to why I'm getting a list index out of range error. I'm trying to add up all the items in the list and using the number as the index for the list. In the end, I wanted all strings in the list to cut off '//'.

```
word_list = []
i = 0

while i < len(word_list):
    word_list.extend(['He//llo', 'Ho//w are yo//u', 'Be///gone'])
    i += 1
    word_list[i].strip('//')
    print(i)

print(word_list[i])
print(i)
```

Comment: @MorganThrapp no he doesn't, the issue is that word_list has no elements when that expression is evaluated

Comment: @BrianO, that is an infinite loop

Comment: Deleted my comment, because, yep! I was ignoring "while" thinking "for", which is surely easier.  But even when slightly fixed up it's going to be an infinite loop ;)

Answer (score 3):

You condition is never True `i < len(word_list)`, `i` is `0` and the so is the length of your list so you never enter the loop. You cannot index an empty list so `print(word_list[i])`  with `i` being `0` gives you an `IndexError`.

Your next problem is adding more items to your list in the loop so if you did start the loop it would be *infinite* as the list size would grow faster than `i`, for example adding a single string to your list initially:

```
word_list = ["foo"]
i = 0

# i will never be greater than len(word_list) so loops infinitely
while i < len(word_list): # never enter i is not < len(wordlist)
    print(i)
    word_list.extend(['He//llo', 'Ho//w are yo//u', 'Be///gone'])
    i += 1
    word_list[i].strip('//')
    print(i)
```

You add `3` elements to your list, you increase `i` by `1` so that equal an infinite loop. Not sure what your goal is but using a while does not seem to be what you really want.

If you wanted to use a loop to replace the `/` and you actually have some strings in your list initially:

```
word_list = ['He//llo', 'Ho//w are yo//u', 'Be///gone']
for i in range(len(word_list)):
    word_list[i] = word_list[i].replace("/","")
    print(i)
```

strings are also *immutable* so you need to reassign the value, you cannot change a string inplace, the above can also simply become a list comp:

```
word_list = ['He//llo', 'Ho//w are yo//u', 'Be///gone']
word_list[:] = [s.replace("/","") for s in word_list]
```

I also used `str.replace` as `strip` only removes from the start and end of strings.

Comment: Not `s.replace("/","")` but `s.replace("//","")` as that's OP's spec. This will turn `'Be///gone'` (possibly a typo) into `'Be/gone'` but so be it; the other strings will be slash-free.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what's happening in the code:

```
word_list = [] # you initialize an empty list with no elements
i = 0 

while i < len(word_list): # word_list has no elements, so its length is zero
                          # so this expression is 'while 0 < 0, *which is false*
                          # so, we skip the loop entirely

print(word_list[i]) # print the word_list[0], the first element of word_list
                    # word_list has not changed, so still has zero elements at this point
                    # error! panic! etc
```

Answer (score 1):

You start with `word_list` equal to `[]` which has length 0, and `i` equal to `0`, thus the `while` loop is never entered (it's false that `0 < 0`). When you try to `print(word_list[i])` you get an `IndexError` because there is no `i`th (`0`th) element in `word_list` -- `word_list` is empty, so index `0` really is out of range.

What you want is presumably:

```
word_list = ['He//llo', 'Ho//w are yo//u', 'Be///gone']
i = 0

while i < len(word_list):
    word_list[i] = word_list[i].replace('//')
    print(i, word_list[i])
    i += 1
```

I say "presumably" because maybe you *do* want the list to grow infinitely and faster than `i` (joke -- see @Padraic Cunningham's answer, which I think you should accept as the correct one).

Answer (score -1):

use for loop, there no need to keep track of indexing with for loop

```
import re

for i, w in enumerate(word_list):
    word_list[i] = re.sub(r'/+','',w)

print(word_list)

['Hello', 'How are you', 'Begone']
```